# How should I set camera to fit the device screen in flame 1.8

Tags: dart, flame

I'm trying to make a RPG style game using Flame 1.8.
This is my onLoad of my game (extends FlameGame):

```
 @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    // debugMode = true;

    myWorld = MyWorld();
    await add(myWorld);

    Flame.device.setLandscape();
    cameraComponent = CameraComponent(world: myWorld);
 
    //cameraComponent.viewfinder.anchor = Anchor.topLeft;

    await add(cameraComponent);
    return super.onLoad();
  }
```

They say you should use this to get the job done:

```
camera.viewport = FixedResolutionViewport(size);
```

But in Flame 1.8 there is no camera property and CamerComponent view port seems to be readonly.
So how can I set my game to fit the device screen size. It works very good on Chrome I just do the math using myGame.size and everthing is where it should be but when I test it on android device some of the components are not shown which should be because their position's top is something like myGame.size.y - (components.size.height) , for example consider this :

```
for (int i = 0; i * 1024 < 20000; i++) {
      var top = game.size.toSize().height - 64;
      add(Brick(position: Vector2(i * 1024, top)));
    }
```

It's in bottom of the screen on firefox but in android device it's not shown and it's like I've done zoom or something ,thank you very much

PS: 64 is the brick's height

PS2: I said viewport is readonly because Code.exe is saying so:

> 'viewport' can't be used as a setter because it's final. Try finding a
> different setter, or making 'viewport' non-final

But this solved my problem :

```
final cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(   world: myWorldComponent,   width: size.x,   height: size.y, );
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewport for the `CameraComponent` needs to passed in to the `CameraComponent` constructor, like this:

```dart
final cameraComponent = CameraComponent(
  world: world,
  viewport: <Your viewport>,
);
```

or for the `FixedResolutionViewport` you can also use the other `CameraComponent` constructor and it will set up the viewport for you:

```dart
final cameraComponent = CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(
  world: myWorldComponent,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the withFixedResolution . You saved me . I almost read the whole document but unfortunately missed this. But VS Code is not agree with the first part : 'viewport' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'viewport' non-final

Comment: @Vahid2023 aah true, it actually is final, I updated my answer.